# SpaceX rocket lifts off on first commercial satellite launch

Tags: prepositions

What's the usage of **on** in *SpaceX rocket lifts off on first commercial satellite launch*? Is it used metaphorically here?

[Source](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/12/04/us-space-spacex-launch-idUSBRE9AS01820131204)

Comment: Its better not to critique the grammar used in titles, as it can be modified for editing or other reasons. Written correctly, this should read like "**The** SpaceX rocket lifts off on its first commercial satellite launch and trip into space.". *On* really refers to the trip, not the launch itself.

Comment: https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?hl=en#newwindow=1&hl=en&q=%22on+its+first+launch%22 I think the search results pretty much show that "trip" is not necessarily required. @user3169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used in the sense of "on the occasion of":

> SpaceX rocket lifts off on the occasion of the first commercial satellite launch

Titles often use shorted sentences that need some "decoding" - it's almost like they developed their own grammar.

You see similar (and worse) things in financial reporting:

> Dow Jones Index drops 70 points on fears of inflation

Similar use of "on" but even more contrived…